How can I run a local k8s cluster on Windows with GPU?
We are exploring a way to run our k8s stack on a Windows workstation and utilize its GPUs.
I have made it work without using GPU by using k8s in Docker Desktop. However, when I install Nvidia Device Plugin, it just couldn't find GPU. I also tried minikube, and ran minikube start --addons=nvidia-driver-installer, but pod nvidia-driver-installer failed with code 32.
I also searched a bit more for other tools like MicroK8s, but it seems it doesn't support GPU on Windows either.
Is there really a working solution for this problem?
